# Changes made in build event are not persisting on clickonce publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce, msbuild-task

I am having issues with changes made by a post build event not persisting when published.

I currently have my project set to append some extra information to the end of a few otherwise static files in the post build event. When I view the resulting files locally (`<some path>\bin\x86\Debug\`) I can verify that the changes have been made.

When I go to view the same files as published by clickonce (in the `<some click once url>\Application Files\<some version>` directory) the files appear without any changes having been made to them.

In addition to a post build event, I have also tried also tried a `BeforePublish` target and still receive the same result:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.Targets" />
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
    <!-- build event here -->
</Target>
```

Can anyone explain why I am experiencing this behavior and suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify files in `obj` folder - that's where they are copied into `publish` folder from. In my app I have the following logic to sign all files for the app:

```
  <Target Name="SignOutput" AfterTargets="CoreCompile" Condition="'$(ConfigurationName)'=='Release'">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TimestampServerUrl>http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll</TimestampServerUrl>
      <ApplicationDescription>MY APP</ApplicationDescription>
      <SigningCertificateCriteria></SigningCertificateCriteria>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <SignableFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Exec Condition=" '$(ConfigurationName)'=='Release'" Command="&quot;c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\signtool.exe&quot; sign $(SigningCertificateCriteria) /d &quot;$(ApplicationDescription)&quot; /t &quot;$(TimestampServerUrl)&quot; &quot;%(SignableFiles.Identity)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

note the

```
Include="$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)"
```

line.